# Performing Sql Alchemy On_conflict_do_update on table with multiple constraints

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

There is a table with one PK and one Unique Foreign Key , I need to perform upsert on it using SQLalchemy's On_conflict_Do_update feature.

I am able to make it work with one constraint with the below query , however , I am unable to do if the table has multiple unique constraints.

```
insert_stmt = insert Table.values()
stmt = insert_stmt.on_conflict_do_update(constraint='some_constraint'set_=dict()
execute(stmt)
```

Is there a way to add multiple constraint names here.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do this with the `constraint` keyword, but you may be able to use [`index_elements` and `index_where`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.Insert.on_conflict_do_update) for this. But it largely depends on your underlying DDL.